# Unexpected Output of c program

Tags: c, if-statement, sizeof, negation, comma-operator

```
    void main()
    {
     clrscr();
     if(sizeof(!6.0))
     printf("%d",sizeof(6.0,2));
     else
     printf("i don't know");
     getch();
    }
```

> The output of this function is **4**. As I can understand in the expression `if(sizeof(!6.0))` -> the expression `sizeof(!6.0)` returns: ***0***
>
> > so `sizeof(0)` is 4 *(in 64 bit system)* and expression `if(sizeof(!6.0))` executes as its `True`. But in `printf("%d",sizeof(6.0,2))` the **output is 4** .
> >
> > > **So I want to know why `sizeof()` is returning 4 byte and how can it take two values without any warning and error by compiler.**

Comment: ```6.0,2``` returns the last element in the comma separated list (2).
2 is of type `int`. `int` is 4 bytes big in your architecture.

Comment: You should really pay more attention to where your parentheses are

Comment: I don't see any reason to dive deep into this material without any context. Nobody writes code like this.

Comment: gcc -Wall says "warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]". Pretty self-explanatory given that you know what the comma operator is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
> the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
> is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
> is an integer constant.

And (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. **The result has type int**. The expression !E is
> equivalent to (0==E).

Thus in this if statement

```
if(sizeof(!6.0))
```

the operand of the `sizeof` operator is an expression with the negation operator `!` and has the type `int`. So in fact you have

```
if(sizeof(int))
```

`sizeof( int )` is never equal to `0` so the expression in the if statement evaluates to logical true and the sub-statement of the if statement

```
printf("%d",sizeof(6.0,2));
```

gets the control.

The operand of this `sizeof` operator  `sizeof(6.0,2)` is an expression with the comma operator.

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
> expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
> of the right operand. **Then the right operand is evaluated; the
> result has its type and value.**

So the type of the expression is `int` that is the type of the second operand that represents the integer constant `2`.

So again the operator is equivalent to `sizeof( int )` and in your system it is equal to `4`.

The compiler did not issue a warning for the expression with the comma operator that the evaluation of the first operand does not have an effect because the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate expressions used as its operands. It only determines the type of expressions.

Pay attention to that you shell to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%d` in this call

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(6.0,2));
```